# How safe it is to perform Das Mahavidya anushthanas or sadhanas?

Tags: tantra, sadhana, dasha-mahavidya

I want to perform Das Mahavidya sadhanas. But I don't know how safe are they? Does anyone has experience of such sadhnas? Which mahavidya sadhna is beneficial to attain success in any field?

Comment: It's better not to write " I have faced huge failures in life, so need grace of a deity to succeed in life." part in the question , otherwise it will look like personal advice question.

Comment: Do you want to perform on your own or under guidance of Guru? You can perform  the sadhana safely under a competent Guru.

Comment: It is safe as long as you're doing it properly, Check this link: https://hindi.speakingtree.in/allslides/dasa-mahavidya-sadhna-puja/280020 . Would be better if you perform it under the guidance of a Guru like TheDestroyer already mentioned. @Deepeshkumar

Comment: This kind of sadhana should be learnt from a competent guru, as others said before. But if you want a better life, it's safer jap nam, or nam sankirtanam. If you haven't a guru, you can repeat your ishta name, or sing bhajans. When you find a real guru, you can ask him about dasha Mahavidya sadhana.

Comment: One becomes qualified to perform such sadhanas only after initiation.

Comment: You can pray with simple mantras and try to keep upasana simple to obtain the grace of goddess.